# How to force an iframe size programmatically?

Tags: iframe-resizer

I'm making a page builder type thing. For normal view the iframe needs to resize accordingly, but for mobile / tablet views it needs to be a set size.

using iframe-resizer https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer by @david-bradshaw

parent window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
....
$("iframe")[0].iFrameResize({
    checkOrigin: false,
    enablePublicMethods     : true,
    heightCalculationMethod: "bodyScroll",
});
....
```

The viewpoint size changer does this :

```
// set the iframes width and height "before" iframeresizer does stuff to make it look seemless    
_this.editor.css({
    "width":mapper[size].width,
    "height":mapper[size].height
})
```

Only way I saw the .size() working is from the iframe itself

```
// fire off a sendMessage cause only way i saw .size() working is from the iframe itself
_this.editor[0].iFrameResizer.sendMessage({
    "width":mapper[size].width,
    "height":mapper[size].height,
    "forceSize":true
});
```

iframe window

```
<script>
    var iFrameResizer = {
        messageCallback: function(message){
            console.log("messageCallback")
            console.log(message)
            if (message.forceSize==true){
                console.log(window.parentIFrame)
                window.parentIFrame.autoResize(false);
                window.parentIFrame.size(message.height); // Set height to 100px
            } else {
                // apply auto resizing again
            }

        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

I was hoping for an easier way like on parent disableIframeResizer() or something, or being able to set .size() from parent since that's where the choose your viewpoint parts live.I  can't seem to figure it out :(

My issue is: I need to somehow tell the iframe not to do its resizing when forceSize = true and then when the message comes in then to resize accordingly .

Thanks for a pretty decent library tho!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question 100%. But I tried to answer your question as best as I understood.

You can set an iframe's size really simply in html. You can also do it with the help of CSS.

You could do this: `<iframe href="https://google.com" width="100%" height="100%">Your Browser Does Not Support Iframe</iframe>`.

You could also set the exact diameter like this: `<iframe href="https://google.com" width="300px" height="100px">Your Browser Does Not Support Iframe</iframe>`

You could also use php to automatically change the diameter of it.

Comment: I'm using the auto resized library linked in above. when initialized it adds events n stuff to automatically resize the iframe to behave like a div etc. looking for a way to disable that library under certain circumstances

Comment: What circumstances would you like the iframe to be removed?

Comment: I'm making a page builder thing. when you view it in pc mode it needs to resize. when you click mobile then it needs to disable the auto resizer and set the height / width